# Creating React app to have multiple roles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, wordpress

How do you create a React website that you can assign multiple roles the way WordPress does it? For example if you are creating a website for a client and the client would be responsible for adding the actual text content without actually altering your code. 
I want to do this as a substitute for using WordPress

Comment: This is far too broad to address in a SO question.

Comment: i know but i just need an opinion on the right step because google it really gives no real result

Comment: Please read [ask] - if you have questions you know aren't appropriate, *don't post them*.